# How to set export path for native library in ubuntu server?

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I don't know how to set export path for ubuntu server.
I tried below one,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/panel/lib"
```

In lib folder contains all .so files. When i export and run, one of the lib files such as "libopencv_core.so.o"  it shows error like cannot open shared object file no such file or directory. But lib folder contains that file.
Please help me how to rectify that issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the new library path, you have to manage the old path in that variable.

If you want add a new path to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, you can follow the below format.

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/panel/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

Because, you need the old value in that variable, that time only the all pthat are there in that variable, For libraries it will search that variable only (Like $PATH for executing a commands).